# Controlling modal using custom hook does not work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, modal-dialog, react-custom-hooks

I want to render `Modal.tsx` in `MyInfoPage.tsx`(or anywhere I want to show modal).
So, I created simple custom hook `useModal.ts` to control `isOpenModal`.
But, I encountered some rendering problem.
When I try to close modal using `closeModal()` in `Modal.tsx`'s backdrop `div` tag, there is any change!
More clearly, `setIsOpenModal(false)` in `closeModal()` which implemented in `useModal.ts` does not work...
Oddly, only `setIsOpenModal` doesn't work! Other code like `console.log()` does work!
I'm very confused about why only `setIsOpenModal(false)` statement doesn't work.
What's wrong with this code? What concept am I confusing?

```js
// MyInfoPage.tsx

// ...import... //

function MyInfoPage(props: MyInfoPageProps) {
  // ... //

  const { isOpenModal, openModal, closeModal } = useModal();

  const cancelClickHandler = () => {
    openModal();
  };

  const pageBackHandler = () => {
    closeModal();
    router.back();
  };

  return (
    <section className={styles.section}>
      {isOpenModal && (
        <Modal>
          <div>
            <button onClick={pageBackHandler}>Yes</button>
            <button onClick={closeModal}>No</button>
          </div>
        </Modal>
      )}

      // .... //
    </section>
  );
}

export default MyInfoPage;
```

```js
// Modal.tsx

// ...import... //

function Modal(props: ModalProps) {
  const { closeModal } = useModal();

  const content = (
    <>
      <div className={styles.backdrop} onClick={closeModal}></div>
      <div className={styles.modal_body}>
        <div>{props.children}</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );

  return createPortal(content, document.getElementById("modal") as HTMLElement);
}

export default Modal;
```

```js
// useModal.ts

// ...import... //

interface UseModalHook {
  isOpenModal: boolean;
  openModal: () => void;
  closeModal: () => void;
}

function useModal(): UseModalHook {
  const [isOpenModal, setIsOpenModal] = useState(false);

  const openModal = () => {
    setIsOpenModal(true);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    setIsOpenModal(false);
  };

  return { isOpenModal, openModal, closeModal };
}

export default useModal;
```

Comment: You're confusing hooks with contexts. Your hook creates a new state for the component that it is used in, but it is not in any way related to the `Modal` component that it's supposed to control. With a Context, you can create a state that can be "consumed" by every component. That means that every component that uses the context talks to the same state. And with that state you can show or hide your modal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
You mean..I confuse between hooks and contextAPI.
And..If I want to control modal using this approach, should use contextAPI not custom hook like this.
In ContextAPI, state is same in anywhere. But, in custom hook, state doesn't shared with other component.  
Did I understand it well?

Comment: That is correct. Although, you still *could* be using custom hooks. But instead of returning a new state in your hook, you return the value from `useContext`.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I'll try both approach!